# Asynchronous HTTPWebRequests C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httpwebrequest

Is it possible to get the response of the HTTPWebRequest class asynchronous?
So that I could use it like this:

```
await GetResponseAsync("google.com");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse method. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for an explanation